# How to get all page names of a spreadsheet file in a column which will keep updating if the page name is changed?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with say following page names:

> "Sheet 1"
>
> "Sheet 2"
>
> "Sheet 3"

Afterwards, I changed name of

> "Sheet 1" -> "Rough"

Is there anyway for me to get a list of all page names of the file in a spreadsheet page in a column?

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

You want to trigger an action when a sheet name is modified (`sheet` here refers to a `tab`, or to a `page`, as you seem to call it). Sheets formulas will not get triggered by a sheet name change.

#### Solution:

You can accomplish this by installing an Apps Script [onChange trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange), which will fire a function you specify `when the spreadsheet's content or structure is changed` (e.g., **when a sheet name is changed**). To do this, you can follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Create an Apps Script function to do the following: (1) retrieve all the sheet names, (2) write these sheet names to a specified sheet. You could use this function, for example. Copy it to the script editor and save the project:

```js
function onChangeTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); // Get current spreadsheet
  var sheetNames = ss.getSheets().map(sheet => [sheet.getName()]); // Get sheet names
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("All Tab Names"); // Change according to your preferences
  destSheet.getRange("A2:A").clearContent(); // Remove previous content
  destSheet.getRange(2, 1, sheetNames.length).setValues(sheetNames);
}
```

- Install the `onChange` trigger to fire the function above, either manually, following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), or [programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically), by running this function once:

```js
function createOnChangeTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onChangeTrigger")
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onChange()
  .create();
}
```

#### Note:

- The function `onChangeTrigger` writes all sheet names to column A of a sheet called `All Tab Names`. Please change that to your sheet name. Also, check [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows) if you want to change the range to which the sheet names are written.

#### Reference:

- [onChange trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange)

Answer (score 0):

You could install this Addon [Formulas](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/formulas_by_top_contributors/515924842729) to use one of its functions  `=UTIL_SHEETNAME()` within a cell of all your sheets (let say in `A1` of every tab), then you would have a master sheet for listing your tabs and where you reference each formula you've used (`=Sheet1!A1`; `=Sheet2!A1`; etc...). But this function doesn't seem to update quickly though.

Alternatively, you could write a code (Apps Script) to list all your tabs, which has been answered everywhere. If you need help with the latter, add in your tags '**Google-Apps-Script**' to add more visibility to your question.